# Java real fixed time interval

Tags: java, timer

I'm doing some tasks using Java. I have some problems with timing: I need to set up a timer with a fixed period of repetition. I tried both, the standard `Timer`, and `TimerTask` and the `ScheduledExecutor`, but both work in an approximate manner, i.e. if I set an interval of 40 milliseconds, using the following code (for `Executors`)

```java
m_executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);       
Runnable thread = new TheThread();
m_executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(thread, 0, 40000000, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

And then I try to print "time" of each execution

```java
private static final class TheThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime()/1000000);
    }
}
```

The result is something like this:

```
xxxxxx300
xxxxxx345
xxxxxx386
xxxxxx428
...
```

As you can see, if I correctly understand `nanoTime()` the function is called at a random intervals, close to that I specified (40 milliseconds), but not exactly what I specified!

When I worked with C and Win32s, for example, I was able to use the `CreateTimerQueueTimer()` function that is highly accurate, and the callback function was called every 40 milliseconds:

```
xxxxxx300
xxxxxx340
xxxxxx380
...
```

I tried to move time measurement to avoid the printing time. I also tried to use `scheduleAtFixedRate()`, but unfortunately the period varies between 35 and 47 ms (set to 40 in the method).

I'm wondering how people can make software such emulators or similar things, that requires a precise period observance...:-)

I thought of a possible solution that I would like to show you and ask to you, experts:) how this idea could be applicable (and safe)

The problem here is to run some methods every X milliseconds, say 40 ms. The question here is about Java timer/timing, but what about this simple solution?

```java
public class MyEmulator extends Thread {
    private long start = 0;
    private long end = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long exec_time; 

        start = System.nanoTime();
   
        /*
         * Do the emulator-loop
         */

        end = System.nanoTime();

        exe_time = (end - start)/1000000;

        // wait with a whil() (40 - exec_time)
    }
}
```

With this solution, when I print the elapsed time after the waiting `whilt()` is ended the result is exactly 40 ms (without decimal, that is not quit important).

Do you think it would be safe, i.e. are really 40 ms?

Comment: The way you are measuring the amount of time the `run` method exectuted for is wrong. You need to calculate it as `current time after print statement ran - current time before print statement ran`.

Comment: I don't think that's what he wants. He simply wants to record the time at which the method was run

Comment: You should take the values you get from `nanoTime()` with a [grain of salt](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/).

Comment: Thank you guys. Well... I understand what @bot says. Too simplify the question... I need to run a task every X milliseconds, where is must be exact! Also 1 ms is too high as an error of approximation. This is because I'm porting my emulator from C to Java, and the computer I'm emulating has a frame rate of 25 fps (or 30 fps if it runs in NTSC). So this kind of jittering influences the overall cpu-loop too much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you're going to be able to manage this in Java with this level of precision. Unlike your C/Win32 solutions, your Java solution is running in a JVM with multiple threads (of varying priority) and with garbage collection running and taking resources.

Having said that, I would experiment with the `scheduleAtFixedRate()` method, which executes at a regular period. `scheduleWithFixedDelay()` will execute and upon completion delay for a fixed amount of time. Hence not accounting for the time taken for your method to actually run.

Comment: Not to forget that the time is printed before the `run` method finishes or after the `run` method is entered so the OP should be accounting for the time lost between the print statement and the entering/return from the run method?

Comment: @bot, yes, you are right, I also set 1 or 2 seconds instead of milliseconds, to give a try. The result still be not accurate.